# Is the on'yomi kanji reading really needed if I'm going to Japan?

Tags: readings, onyomi

Is the on'yomi kanji reading really needed if I'm going to Japan?

Comment: Why woud it not be? Many, many common words are on'yomi, such as ご飯｛ごはん｝, 学校｛がっこう｝, and 結構｛けっこう｝.

Comment: I'm wondering what made you think the necessity of on'yomi might be different from that of kun'yomi.

Comment: 

Answer (score 5):

> Is the on'yomi kanji reading really needed if I'm going to Japan?

Depends.

- Are you going to Japan to sight-see, and you don't care to read signs, menus, media?
   
  Then, **no**, you don't need to learn the *on'yomi* of the kanji.
- Are you going to Japan to study or otherwise immerse yourself in the culture, and you want to be able to read?
   
  Then, **yes, absolutely**, you need to learn the *on'yomi* of the kanji.

As user @[Angelos](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/9971/) noted in their [comment](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/91144/is-the-onyomi-kanji-reading-really-needed-if-im-going-to-japan#comment-148763), many Japanese words that are spelled in kanji are only read with the *on'yomi*.  Many of these words are very basic vocabulary.

If you don't learn the *on'yomi* of the kanji, you will be functionally illiterate.  Whether learning the *on'yomi* is "really needed" all comes down to what you yourself personally need for your trip.